# WinForms передать параметры в запущенное приложение

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

У меня есть приложение WinForms, которое запускается с параметрами (номер телефона, ФИО, номер клиента).
Для передачи новых параметров сейчас используется запуск копии с новыми параметрами, а ранее запущенное закрывается через Kill.
Можно ли как-то передать параметры в старое приложение, не убивая его?

Answer (score 1):

Можно при запуске нового экземпляра отправлять аргументы в старый, после чего новый закрывать

Вот клиент

```
if (Process.GetProcesses().Select(x => x.ProcessName).Count(s => s == Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName) > 1)
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect("localhost", 6565);
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(args[0]);
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    client.Close();
    return;
}
```

Вот сервер

```
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 6565);
    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listener.Start();
        listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(Newarg, null);
        label1.Text = Program.Arg;
    }

    private void Newarg(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
        var client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
        client.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, 128);
        client.Close();
        Program.Arg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        label1.Invoke(new Action(() => { label1.Text = Program.Arg; }));
        listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(Newarg, null);
    }
```

[А вот весь код](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rUYlNzS1dSZyo_QCwhcDBJl_7upXDFfi)